# Сборка релиза Qt

Tags: qt, компиляция, qt5, сборка

Как собрать проект в Qt Creator без `cpp` и `o` файлов?
Я к тому, что при сборке проекта в режиме "Выпуск" в каталоге `release` создается куча файлов. Хотелось бы чтобы файл был 1 - `exe`. Я не говорю про статическую линковку, меня вполне устраивает, что мое приложение будет работать только с рядом лежащими qt библиотеками. В общем как правильно настроить компиляцию, чтобы получился 1 exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так, я сам разобрался. Оказывается exe может работать без этих файлов...